# nth Child in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have used nth child before but for some reason can not target the correct div:

```
<div class='main'>...</div>
  <div class='color'>...</div>
  <div class='number'>...</div>
    <div class='target_div'>...</div>
      <div class='target_me_one'>...</div>
      <div class='target_me_two'>...</div>
<div class='main'>...</div>
<div class='main'>...</div>
<div class='main'>...</div>
<div class='main'>...</div>
<div class='main'>...</div>
<div class='main'>...</div>
```

I was hoping for the first occurrence of main, the second child of main (number), the first child of number (target_div) and then both of the children of target_div.

The whole objective of this is to alter target_me_one / target_me_two all from the first occurrence of main. I can not target these two individually through selectors (due to the plug in I'm using).

Is this possible or am I way off???

Comment: The divs are just indented that way in your example. They are not actual child elements. may be that is the cause of the issue. If that is not, edit the question with the selector your are using to target. Preferably a fiddle with the minimal code that can reproduce the issue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you are expecting, without relying on classes for specific selectors. Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5nrutdk/)

```
      .main:first-of-type > *:nth-child(2) > *:nth-child(1) * {
        color: red;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "first-of-type" instead of n-th child.

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m395kdxy/

```
    .main:first-of-type .target_me_one {
        background: #ff0000;
    }

    .main:first-of-type .target_me_two {
        background: #ff0000;
    }
```

Please let me know if it works

Comment: thanks masum7. this is a good solution too. the one xian posted was a bit more what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any child elements to select.

What you are probably thinking of is the `:nth-of-type` selector.

e.g.:

```
.main{
    /* All */
}

.main:nth-of-type(1){
    /* First */
}

.main:nth-of-type(2){
    /* Second */
}
```

[See the documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp).

As usual, note that this does not work in IE <9.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. you're right, :nth-of-type was what i was looking for.